# spark sql Insert into HIVE external partitioned table takes more time

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark sql statement that inserts data into a Hive external partitioned table. The insert takes more than  30 minutes to complete for just 200k data.

I have tried to increase the executor.memoryOverhead to 4086. still i see the same time in the insert statement.

This is the values given for the execution.

`--executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 3G --num-executors 25 --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4096 --driver-memory 4g`

Spark Code:

````
        Table_1.createOrReplaceTempView(tempViewName)

        config = self.context.get_config()

        insert_query = config['tables']['hive']['1']['insertStatement']
        insertStatement = insert_query + tempViewName

        self.spark.sql(insertStatement)
        self.logger.info("************insert completed************")
        repairTableQuery = config['tables']['hive']['training']['repairtable']

        self.spark.sql(repairTableQuery)
        self.logger.info("************repair completed************")
        end = datetime.now()```

Would doing a coalesce partition before insert statement help in faster execution.
````

Comment: Could you please provide the actual query code, size of cluster, data storage (HDFS ?), size of the table, partition size, shuffle data, DAG for the same ?